# $X$ is at most countable iff there is a $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at the proof of the following proposition:

Let $X \neq \varnothing$. $X$ is at most countable iff there is a $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$.

Proof:

"$\Rightarrow$" If $X$ is infinite, then obviously there is a $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$.

If $X$ is finite then $X \sim n$ for some $n \in \omega, n \neq 0$ since $X \neq \varnothing$.

We define the extension $f$ of $g$ at $\omega$:

$$f(k)=g(k) \text{ for } k<n \\ f(k)=g(0) \text{ for } k \geq n$$

and obviously  $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$

"$\Leftarrow$" We assume that $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$.

For each $a \in A$ we define $S_a=f^{-1}(\{a\})$.

Since $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} X$ the set $S_a$ is nonempty for each $a \in X$.
So there is the $\min S_a$ for each $a \in X$. We define $h(a)=\min S_a$ for all $a \in X$.

For $a \neq b$ with $a,b \in X$ we have $h(a) \neq h(b)$ since $S_a \neq S_b$. So $h: X \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow} \omega$

Thus, $X$ is at most coutable.

I haven't understood why we can define $S_a=f^{-1}(\{a\})$.

We know that if $n \in \omega$ and $x \in X$, it can be $f(n)=x$.

But in this case we take $f(S_a)=\{a\}$.
:confused:

Comment: $S_a\subseteq \omega$ is the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that $f(n) = a$. That is what $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ means. It's all numbers that "hit" $a$ as you apply $f$ to them.

Comment: @Arthur So we have $f(n)=x, n \in \omega, x \in X \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)=n$. Does this mean that $S_a$ is a set that contains all possible $n$ such that $f^{-1}(x)=n$?

Comment: Almost. $S_a$ is _the_ set containing all possible $n$ and nothing else.

Comment: Why does the fact that $f: \omega \to X$ is surjective imply that $S_a$ is non-empty for each $a \in X$? @Arthur

Comment: Because that's what surjective means: For every $a\in X$ there is _some_ $n\in \omega$ such that $f(n) =a$. Therefore $n\in S_a$. There might be more than one, but surjective doesn't say anything about that, and it's not really relevant.